# Distribution of the ratio of two normally distributed variables

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose $X$~$N(\mu_X,\sigma^2_X)$ and $Y$~$N(\mu_Y,\sigma^2_Y)$ are independent, then how is $Z=\frac{X}{Y}$ distributed? (what is mean and variance for $Z$?)

Comment: This should be a simple exercise since you know the distribution of $Z$ (the density even!). What have you tried?

Comment: @WilliamM. When I divide density function of $X$ to density function of $Y$, I get a joint normal probability density function, but I want to find $Z$'s pdf in a uniform form.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Normal_ratio_distributions